# Jquery Image Slide in Slide out with next image

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

The following jquery image slider works perfectly.  the current image disappears and new image comes in with "sildeLeft" effect. instead of that, i'd like to change the disappearance to "slideRight" followed by the next image. but cant figure out how ...thanks to the original uploader for this code..

CSS

```
#exampleSlider {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*** SPECIAL FX ***/

.slideLeft {
  animation-name: slideLeft;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  visibility: visible!important
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(150%)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-8%)
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateX(4%)
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-4%)
  }
  95% {
    transform: translateX(2%)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%)
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(150%)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-8%)
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(4%)
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-4%)
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2%)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%)
  }
}

.slideRight {
  animation-name: slideRight;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideRight;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  visibility: visible!important
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-150%)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(8%)
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateX(-4%)
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(4%)
  }
  95% {
    transform: translateX(-2%)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%)
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(8%)
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-4%)
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(4%)
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2%)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%)
  }
}
```

jQuery

```
 $(function () {

  /* SET PARAMETERS */
  var change_img_time = 5000;
  var transition_speed = 600;
  var fxArr = ['slideLeft'];


  var specialfx = 'rand';

  var simple_slideshow = $("#exampleSlider"),
    listItems = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
    listLen = listItems.length,
    i = 0,

    changeList = function () {
      listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
        i += 1;
        if (i === listLen) {
          i = 0;
        }

        if (specialfx == 'rand') {
          randfx = fxArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * fxArr.length)];
          specialfx = randfx;
        }

        listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed).addClass(specialfx);
      });

    };

  listItems.not(':first').hide();
  setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);

});
```